# Como recuperar o ID do último registro inserido no banco?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel

Como faço para recuperar o id do último registro feito em uma tabela no banco de dados?

Estou usando o Laravel. Antes de usar um framework eu usava o `LASTINSERT`.

Comment: Depende do BD utilizado. Que framework / linguagem?

Comment: Tente melhorar a sua pergunta para facilitar a percepção da sua necessidade. Framework? Qual? Que linguagem?

Comment: Por favor especifique o `framework` e linguagem que você está utilizando, para podermos lhe auxiliar, lembrando a maioria do `frameworks` de persistência que eu conheço, pelo menos, já tem essa função implemantando por default, por exemplo o `Hibernate`, ao persistir um objeto o `framework` já seta o `ID` gerado pelo banco de dados no objeto.

Comment: Informe, linguagem e Banco de Dados, se for MySQL é LAST_INSERT_ID e em cada banco é uma forma e em PDO e MySQLi ja tem implementado isso

Comment: O Laravel por padrão trabalha com sqlite, mysql, postgresql e sqlserver, e o mesmo já está implementado como é o último id inserido e com resposta seria de Antonio Carlos Ribeiro, poderiamos melhorar e divulgar tal informação visto que aqui ta crescendo e muito as perguntas sobre laravel php ? user7834 melhore a sua questão para que permanece e não feche a mesma!

Answer (score 6):

Se você utilizar Eloquent, isso é feito automaticamente, independentemente do sistema de banco de dados:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

}

$post = Post::create(['title' => 'Laravel']);

echo $post->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::Query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
```

De acordo com este post aqui: [laravel raw queries last_insert_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299493/laravel-raw-queries-last-insert-id)

Comment: obrigado Lucas Henrique, me ajudou muito.

Comment: @user7834 Se a resposta tiver ajudado a solucionar o problema, dê uma ajuda e marque como resposta "aceita".

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver usando PDO no Laravel a forma correta é:

```
$id = DB::connection('mysql')->pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Se o banco não for MySQL altere isso no código acima.

Comment: Então Leo, eu estou usando o framework laravel e não o PDO, já usei bastante PDO e nesses casos era bem fácil pegar o lastinsert, será que o laravel tem alguma forma nativa para pegar o último id de um registro?